# enum casting (compile and does not compile)

Tags: c#, enums

Why does addition require a cast?
**Any help?**

```
public enum _enum
{
    A = 12,
    B = 20,
    C = 30
}

var Sub = _enum.A - _enum.B; // Compiles
var Add = _enum.A + _enum.B; // Does not compile
var Add2 = (int)_enum.A + _enum.B; // Compiles
```

Comment: Please refer this discussion : 

[here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882189/enum-addition-vs-subtraction-and-casting