# Did Microsoft change how C# compiler processes plus-operator on enums? VS 2015.3

Tags: c#, enums, visual-studio-2015

Before upgrade of Visual Studio 2015 to Update 3, things like this used to work.

**C# 5**

Consider we have some enum (where `int` is underlying type), and the expression

```
intVal + enumVal
```

The result of `plus operator` appeared to have the type of `enumVal`.

This is well-described here: [S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6882210/468125)

**And luckily it continues to work.**

---

Such an invocation used to work as well:

```
(int?)intVal + enumVal
```

It gave the `Nullable<type_of_enumVal>` as a resulting type.

**And luckily it continues to work as well.**

---

If we change first arg to some `CustomType` (a struct, not enum) which can be cast to `int?`, then it used to work as well:

```
(CustomType)intVal + enumVal
```

Providing the `Nullable<type_of_enumVal>` as a resulting type.

With Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 it gives the compiler error.

Is it something non-documented that apparently started being off the rules/spec?

P.S. I know that's a bad practice of such operator application over these types of params etc, just out of curiosity.

Comment: Are you sure it used to work?  Your linked question says that adding two Enums together would *not* compile. I've assumed `CustomType` is also an enum, but it's not clear from the question.

Comment: @CharlesMager: I'll update the question now to clarify.

Comment: So you mean a struct that has an implicit conversion to `int?` defined?

Comment: A [mcve] would have been useful.  I've created one [in this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ULQhAL) which, as you can see, *does* compile in this case. I've tried in VS 2015 Update 3 and can confirm this *does not* compile. If I add the cast to `int?`, it compiles (but ReSharper says I can remove it). Interesting!

Comment: Out of curiosity what does ((CustomType)intVal) + enumVal
 do?

Comment: @PaulSwetz: it was taken as an excerpt from a bigger piece of code, which eventually calculates kind of hash code.

Comment: I mean with the parentheses I added in the comment. I'm wondering if they alter the casting in any way.