# Treating an enum like an array?

Tags: c#, enums

I just wanted to ask a question regarding Enums. I got an Enum that looks like this:

```
public enum CameraPosition
{
    ROOM_1,
    ROOM_2,
    ROOM_3
}
```

So what I want to do is for example, that I am currently using a value that is represented by `ROOM_2`. Now I press a button, that's supposed to switch it to the value represented by `ROOM_1`, but without having to hardcode the case of going from `ROOM_2` to `ROOM_1`.

So if my cached value is defined like this:

```
CameraPosition pos = CameraPosition.ROOM_2;
```

I want to do something like this:

```
pos = CameraPosition.ROOM_2 - 1;
```

And that would mean that that `pos` is now `ROOM_1`.

Is this possible to do with Enums, or would I have to roll my own sort of solution to achieve it? Maybe another approach ._.

Comment: Yes, you can - enum values are simple integers in C#.  In your UI, though, are you wanting to cycle through the cameras?  Because if you have one button per camera, you can simply use the CameraPosition as a property of the button.  Then you just copy that value into "pos" in the click event.  No math involved that way.

Comment: @theGleep Oh no, it's one camera in the scene. I just change it's position. Probably two buttons, one for going "One room up" and one for going "One Room Down".

Comment: 'k...yeah, math is probably needed, then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  By default in C#, enums are ints ([see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum)).  You can explicitly set values if you like or allow it to start with 0.  Also see the first answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882189/enum-addition-vs-subtraction-and-casting).

Comment: Hey okay, thanks! I've not really used enums in this way so I thought I'd ask.